# Ruby on Rails Multiple has_many choice in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, tree, has-many

I have two tables in my rails application Categories and Projects. The relationship between both is has_many both ways, meaning Project `has_may` Categories and Categories has_many Projects. The Categories tables are setup as a tree so that each category which is not a root has a father.

I am interested in changing the `new` and `edit` action form so that multiple categories can be selected in the process with a tree checkbox display. If possible i would also like any checking of a node on the category tree to select its whole subtree (all it's descendants). Of course the `new` and `edit` action must create the `has_many` dependencies.

Thanks,
Nachshon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#readme)? I think you could just do

```
<%= f.inputs :categories, :as => :checkboxes %> // :as => :select is another option
```

with it. I'm not sure how to do it with basic ActionView::FormBuilder though.

Comment: Should be ":as => :check_boxes" (underscore)